# windows cant find dll even thought its in a directory in the PATH

Tags: c++, windows, cl

I have cpp file called funner.cpp which i compiled down to a dll file by using the following command: (using microsofts CL compiler, btw)

```
   cl /LD funner.cpp
```

that generated the following files: funner.lib, funner.dll.

i then created another cpp file called mainer.cpp which calls a function within the dll.

i compiled that file using this command:

```
   cl mainer.cpp /link funner.lib
```

that, then, generated an executable file, called mainer.exe.

When i run mainer.exe the program runs as expected and i get no errors what so ever. (as long as the funner.dll file is in the same directory)

however i would like to move the funner.dll to another directory somewhere else, say:

```
   c:\my_dlls\
```

so i did that and then i added the folder to my system PATH variable.

i then tried running the executable but it threw me an error saying that the dll was missing?

but doesn't windows search all the directories in the PATH variable for dlls ?

why cant it find my dll?

Comment: im just running it from the command line :\

Comment: open a new command line. The command line will not update its path until you open a new one.

Comment: nevermind, that actually did work. thanks. feel free to make it an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line does not receive the updated `PATH` until you close and reopen it.

Open a new command line and call the executable from there.

Comment: When you use the control panel environment-variable editor, it broadcasts a `WM_SETTTINGCHANGE` message to top-level windows to inform them that the persistent registry values have been modified. Programs can respond to this message by reloading their environment, but usually only Explorer does. Subsequently any program launched from Explorer will inherit the updated environment. CMD itself never sees the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message because it doesn't host any windows, so it has to be restarted from Explorer.

Comment: The first comment probably should be added to the answer.